Is there a convenient way to index a pandas dataframe based on the approximate location of a number?
I am analyzing some optical spectra data and my dataframe indices are numbers that have some 9 decimal place accuracy. If I don't type in the exact index, the dataframe won't return a value. I am having to use df.iloc(N), but this requires me to continue guessing which index is closest to the desired index. Isn't there some way where I type in df[600], it provides me index closest to that number?
I tried iloc. There is also the over the top tedious solution of first locating the index manually,
df.index[np.abs(df.index - target_value).argmin()]   

and then using that index, but isn't there some faster way to do this?

Is your index sorted? Do you want to find absolutely one match? Or up to a threshold? Can you have more than one match?

Yes, its sorted monotonically, and because of how many decimal places exist, it will almost always be one match. The index was generated by a cubic function so index - desired value will not have multiple matches

Is it possible to calculate that cubic function roots, may be with np.roots?

The pandas out-of-the-box way would be to merge_asof:
pd.merge_asof(pd.DataFrame(index=[0.487948, 0.6432008]), 
              df, left_index=True, right_index=True,
              direction='nearest')

If you want a fast approach, you could use a variant of this excellent approach based on numpy.searchsorted:
def get_closest(df, values):
    # get index as numpy array
    a = df.index.to_numpy()

    # get insert positions
    idxs = np.searchsorted(a, values, side="left")
    
    # find indexes where previous index is closer
    prev_idx_is_less = ((idxs == len(a)) |
                         (np.fabs(values - a[np.maximum(idxs-1, 0)])
                        < np.fabs(values - a[np.minimum(idxs, len(a)-1)])))
    idxs[prev_idx_is_less] -= 1
    
    # index DataFrame
    return df.loc[a[idxs]]

get_closest(df, [0.487948])
#           col
# 0.437587    2

get_closest(df, [0.487948, 0.6432008])
#           col
# 0.437587    2
# 0.645894    6


To find the nearest, Use: from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
let's take a simple example for better understanding :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import time

# A large dataset with 1 million rows
np.random.seed(0)
index_values = np.random.rand(1_000_000) * 1_000_000  # Random values scaled up for variety
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(1_000_000, 1))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index_values, columns=['col'])

target_values = [150_000.123456789, 750_000.987654321]

nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors =1,algorithm ='auto')\
    .fit(df.index.values.reshape(-1,1))

dist,idx = nn.kneighbors(np.array(target_values).reshape(-1,1))

closest_indices = df.index[idx.flatten()]

res = df.loc[closest_indices] 
print(res)
"""
              col
150000.401425   71
750001.853866   79
"""

method 2 :
Use : from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree


# A large dataset with 1 million rows
np.random.seed(0)
index_values = np.random.rand(1_000_000) * 1_000_000  
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(1_000_000, 1))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index_values, columns=['col'])
print(df.head())
target_values = [150_000.123456789, 750_000.987654321]

tree = KDTree(df.index.values.reshape(-1,1))
print(tree)
dist,idx = tree.query(np.array(target_values).reshape(-1,1))
print(dist)#[0.050361  0.0026932]
print(idx)#[0 1]
closest_indices = df.index[idx]
print(closest_indices)#Index([0.437587, 0.645894], dtype='float64')
res = df.loc[closest_indices]
print(res)
"""
              col
150000.401425   71
750001.853866   79
"""

